# Efficient way to utilise Parallel features to make use of many cores

Tags: parallelization

Let's say I have 100 cores/kernels as my disposal and want to compute a function of two variables `f[x,y]` over `{x,1,10}`, `{y,0,59}`. So in total 600 data points. Ideally I would like to utilize all 100 cores giving each core 6 data points to compute. How can I achieve this?

```
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 1, 10 }]
```

Would only parallelize on the first 60 cores and give each core a workload of 10 points and

```
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {x, 1, 10 }, {y, 0, 59 }]
```

would do even worse- parallelizing on the first 10 cores and giving each a workload of 60 points.

I think doing

```
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 1, 3 }];
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 4, 6 }];
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 7, 10}];
```

Would only evaluate the three calls sequentially when the previous `ParallelTable` had finished so would also do not better?

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually work around this by first generating all argument combinations, then using `ParallelMap`:

```
ParallelMap[f, Tuples[{Range[0,59], Range[1,10]}]]
```

You'll need to define your function so that it takes the form `f[{x,y}]`, not `f[x,y]`.

Often it is more practical to use the form

```
ParallelTable[{arg, f[arg]}, {arg, Tuples[{Range[0,59], Range[1,10]}]}]
```

as this will save both the result and the arguments in the output.

Note that this method gives you a flat 1D list, not a 2D one like a `Table` with two iterators would.  If you do need a 2D table, use `Partition` or `ArrayReshape` (v9) on the result.

Comment: Or you could use `f @@ # &`. (+1)

Comment: +1 for anticipating and bettering my offer ;-) I literally didn't see this until you posted.  Ah, well... something to which I can aspire.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, this is going to save me a lot of time.

Comment: @Jagra This happens all the time here on SE :)  it happened to me countless times that just before I finished typing my answer I saw the "new answer" notification

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `EvaluationsPerKernel` option for `Method`:

```
ParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59}, {x, 1, 10},
              Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 6]
```

To check and see if it's doing what you want, you can `Tally` the number of evaluations assigned to each kernel:

```
Tally@Flatten@ParallelTable[$KernelID, {y, 0, 59}, {x, 1, 10}, 
                            Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 6]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs problem, which is that ParallelTable only parallelisms with respect to the 1st iterator.  If your first iterator is `{y,0,59}`, it will never use more than 60 kernels, even if a 100 are available.

Comment: Yikes, I wasn't aware of that limitation. Seems like a really easy thing for them to fix.

Comment: No, it appears that it only parallelizes over the first index. See @Szabolcs's answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yep, that is the problem. Is there no way around this then?

Answer (score 2):

`ParallelMap` method has an apparent downside, that is it will eliminate the parameter names.

from this line of code

```
ParallelMap[f, Tuples[{Range[0,59], Range[1,10]}]]
```

you won't know directly the meaning of first `Range` and second `Range`

But with the latest powerful feature of `Inactivate` and `Activate` of Mathematica 10.

We could improve this using the following code

```
ParallelMap[Activate,Flatten@Table[Inactivate@f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 1, 10 }]
```

I think is more clear than Szabolcs's `ParallelMap` approach.

and you could also define a function

```
Clear[finestParallelTable]
SetAttributes[finestParallelTable,HoldAll]
finestParallelTable[expr_,parameter__]:=
ParallelMap[Activate,Flatten@Table[Inactivate@expr,parameter]]
```

Now

```
finestParallelTable[f[x, y], {y, 0, 59 }, {x, 1, 10 }]
```

Looks exactly the same as the original `ParallelTable`.

Finally, of course the result is a flat list, you could reshape it later or directly add the reshape feature into the function `finestParallelTable`

Answer (score 1):

``Perhaps just an extended comment (with some speculation) rather than a specific answer, but I'll hazard a few lines.

I think you've made some assumptions about how `ParallelTable` works that you may have as an artifact of procedural coding?  Mathematica and specifically `ParallelTable` might, but ought not to have to loop through nested loops.

(Note: @Szabolcs comment above that `ParallelTable` only parallels "...with respect to the 1st iterator."  I'd have guessed it was cleverer than that).

As all of the applications of your function `f` stand independent, I see no reason that Mathematica wouldn't employ all available kernels to calculate them.  Positing equal time for each calculation, it could employ each of your 100 available kernels 6 times.

Kind of interesting to think about how Mathematica might do this internally.  Why wouldn't it create a matrix of all the paired x's and y's then run `f` on them.

You might try creating such a matrix then just `Map` or `ParallelMap` `f` to the matrix.

You can monitor this to some degree from the `Evaluation` menu item.  Click through to `Parallel Status` and observe as you run the calculation.

Comment: the matrix of pairs and `ParallelMap` might just be the way to go, thanks.