# How to parallel this nested table efficiently?

Tags: parallelization, list-manipulation

I have an 8 core CPU and want to parallel evaluate the following nested `Table`

```
Table[Table[expr[i,j], {i,1,10}], {j,1,4}]
```

But there is a problem, the time cost of evaluating `expr[i,j]` increases with the value of variable `i`. If `expr[1,j]` takes 5min, `expr[2,j]` will take 10min and `expr[10,j]` will take 3hours. Now you see, no matter where I will put `Parallel`, in the outer `Table` or in the inner `Table`, the efficiency will not change.

The best way would be to first evaluate the most time consuming terms `expr[10,1]`, `expr[10,2]`, `expr[10,3]`, `expr[10,4]` and other expressions with less time cost just throw onto the remaining core one by one. I naively tried several parallel order, for example

```
ParallelTable[expr[i,j], {i,10,1,-1}, {j,1,4}]
```

but this will not use 4 cores out of my 8 cores. The question is what is the best way to parallelize this nested table evaluation?

Comment: After writing my (updated) answer it seemed strangely familiar.  I believe we have a duplicate: [(20713)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20713/121) -- please review that Q&A; if you agree this is a duplicate I will close and delete my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yeah the problem is alike. But I have a question. You suggest in the comment to use f @@ # & to get f[i,j]. What if my function is `f[parameter1,i,parameter2,j]`?

Comment: If I understand you would want `f[parameter1, #, parameter2, #2]& @@ # &` or perhaps better in that case: `f[parameter1, #[[1]], parameter2, #[[2]] ]&`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Damn! How could I be so stupid. Just a little trick. Why it just can't come into my mind. Thank you, Mr. Wizard

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself.  I make lots of mistakes, and miss or forget plenty of good "tricks."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar question to [Efficient way to utilise Parallel features to make use of many cores](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20713/efficient-way-to-utilise-parallel-features-to-make-use-of-many-cores).

However, in addition to the answers there you need to know:

If the times for each evaluation of `expr` are long, even if not nearly as long as you describe, you will not benefit from queuing multiple operations per kernel.  Instead an algorithm that merely waits for a free kernel is appropriate.  As the documentation for [`Parallelize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Parallelize.html) states:

> `Method -> "FinestGrained"` is suitable for computations involving few subunits whose evaluations take different amounts of time. It leads to higher overhead, but maximizes load balancing.

Combining this with a variation Szabolcs's `Tuples` and `ParallelMap` method:

```
ParallelMap[Labeled[Pause[RandomReal[{0, 0.1}]]; {#[[2]], #[[1]]}, $KernelID] &, 
  Tuples@Range@{4, 10}, Method -> "FinestGrained"] ~Partition~ 10
```

[image]

Comment: I am afraid that setting "finestGrained" is the same. Try `ParallelTable[Labeled[Framed[i, j], $KernelID], {j, 1, 4}, {i, 1, 10},
  Method -> "FinestGrained"]`

Comment: @matheorem Hm... I see.  I didn't actually try this before answering; that's always poor.  Let me look at this again.

Comment: @matheorem Answer updated.

Comment: What does `pause` do?

Comment: @matheorem That was just there to simulate the function evaluation taking a variable amount of time.

Comment: I think my question maybe just a little different to that "Efficient way to utilise Parallel features to make use of many cores". Because in my case, the `Method -> "FinestGrained"` is essential to guarantee evaluation order.

Comment: @matheorem I'm going to reopen this question based on that statement.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that I use is:

```
ParallelMap[(#/.ft->f)&, Flatten[Table[ft[a,b],{a,1,10},{b,1,10}],1]]
```

where f is the function I want to evaluate in parallel on my 80 kernels and ft is some previously undefined symbol.
I find this solution a bit ugly but practical.

Comment: typically, the command would look like:  ParallelMap[(#/.ft->f)&, Flatten[Table[{a,b,ft[a,b]},{a,1,10},{b,1,10}],1]]  which then allows me to build an interpolating function from the results.